# Selenium Element is not clickable at point with ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable

Tags: selenium

I have a problem with the following exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1128, 997). Other element would receive the click...

My page object has a "buy now" button which I want to click.

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='summary-right-column-wrapper']/div[3]/a")
private WebElement buyNow;
```

And I have a getter with a explicit wait build in:

```
public WebElement getBuyNow() {
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buyNow));
}
```

When I call it:

```
final WebElement readyBuyNow = getBuyNow();
readyBuyNow.click();
```

I get the exception.

Why the element is still not clickable if I use the `ExpectedConditions`already?

Thanks!
Best regards
Robert

Comment: Are you are trying to click on the element after page loading/after  closing popup ???? .Bcoz as per your error message I came to know that , you are trying to click element is not yet visible.so  it is clicking on other element

Comment: How can I tell Selenium that it should execute the click after the page is completely loaded? Is it not the default behaviour?

Comment: for that first you need to wait until the element is visible then you can perform action on it

Comment: I do it already with ``ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buyNow)``.

Comment: Do it for  ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(buyNow)

Comment: @QAMember that method checks exactly the same in terms of visibility, will not help

Comment: The ``visibilityOfElementLocated`` method needs a selector as an argument and not a ``WebElement``. This does not really good corresponds with my page objects where I already define selectors as annotations. I would repeat them.

Answer (score 3):

The expected condition `elementToBeClickable` checks two things:

- Visibility: it's not hidden per CSS rules (`display: none`)and has a height and width > 0
- Clickable: the element may not have a `disabled` attribute

It's perfectly possible that those conditions are met and you're still getting that specific exception.

The *most likely* reason is some sort of pop-up, menu or autocomplete box appears over the element you're trying to click (which means nothing to Selenium in terms of 'visibility').

**Solution**: make sure you close any elements hovering over the item you're trying to click.
Without having your specific website to test on, that's the best answer I can give (and it has been the solution for me every time I had this issue).

Comment: Thank you, but there are no elements hovering my targets. The page simply needs more time to load. As a workaround I use a sleep method for that.

Comment: Sleep is really bad crutch. Of course your code and do what  you want. You should use ExpectedConditions, to wait for visibility of some element which is visible only after page loaded - your "buy" button might be a good candidate.

Comment: @RobertMoszczynski It's possible what you're saying but the "Other element would receive the click" most definitely means your target element is already (or should be) visible. Do you have an URL to test on?

Comment: @RobertMoszczynski And are you sure your locator is selecting the element you want? Maybe there's a second element with the same locator, in which case you might select the wrong one.

Comment: 1. No, there is no public link to test on. 2. The locator is ok. Maybe there are multiple elements with the same `ìd``. I'll check it.